# compare all data in each column in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, case

I have a table as follows

```
  OrderId   Carrier Truck   Trailer
  10001     ABC     TruckA  TrailerA
  10001     ABC     TruckA  TrailerA
  10001     ABC     TruckB  TrailerA
  10001     ABC     TruckC  TrailerB
  10001     ABC     TruckC  TrailerD
```

The Output of my query should be single row

```
 OrderId   Carrier Truck   Trailer
 10001     ABC     NULL    NULL
```

The logic have to be applied as if the each column contains the same value then that value have to be in that particular column otherwise it would be NULL

I tried the below queries, but not getting correct output

```
  SELECT 
        s.OrderId
       ,LEAD(s.OrderId,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.Code) AS PreviousOrderId
       ,c.LegalName AS CarrierName
       ,LEAD(c.LegalName,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.Code) AS PreviousCarrierName
       ,t.TruckLicensePlate
       ,LEAD(t.TruckLicensePlate,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.Code) AS PreviousTruckLicensePlate
       ,t.TrailerLicensePlate
       ,LEAD(t.TrailerLicensePlate,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.Code) AS PreviousTrailerLicensePlate
    INTO #tempResult
    FROM
       OrderDetails

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN t.OrderId = t.PreviousOrderId 
             THEN t.OrderId ELSE NULL END AS OrderId
        ,CASE WHEN t.CarrierName = t.PreviousCarrierName
             THEN t.CarrierName ELSE NULL END AS CarrierName
        ,CASE WHEN t.TruckLicensePlate = t.PreviousTruckLicensePlate
             THEN t.TruckLicensePlate ELSE NULL END AS TruckLicensePlate
        ,CASE WHEN t.TrailerLicensePlate = t.PreviousTrailerLicensePlate
             THEN t.TrailerLicensePlate ELSE NULL END AS TrailerLicensePlate
    from #tempResult  t
    order by orderid desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just use a `CASE` with `COUNT` and `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT CASE COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(OrderID) END AS OrderID,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Carrier) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(Carrier) END AS Carrier,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Truck) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(Truck) END AS Truck,
       CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Trailer) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(Trailer) END AS Trailer
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 4):

> The logic have to be applied as if the each column contains the same value then that value have to be in that particular column otherwise it would be NULL

Use aggregation and conditional logic. I find that comparing `min()` and `max()` is a straight-forward approach:

```
select
    orderid,
    case when min(carrier) = max(carrier) then min(carrier) end carrier,
    case when min(truck)   = max(truck)   then min(carrier) end truck,
    case when min(trailer) = max(trailer) then min(carrier) end trailer
from orderdetails
group by orderid
```